# Does this ruby pattern adhere to the single responsibility principle?

Tags: ruby, oop

Does the single responsibility principle (SRP) apply to the text of a file that defines a class?  Or does it apply to the live object when running the program?

I am on a project and we are pulling code out of a model class and putting it in a module.   We are doing this in order to adhere to single responsibility.

We are changing this:

```
class User
  ... lots of other code

  def convert_attributes
     { username: self.email , name: "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}" }
  end
end
```

to something like this

```
class User
  include UserAttributeConverter

  ... lots of other code
end


module UserAttributeConverter
 def convert_attributes
     { username: self.email , name: "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}" }
  end
end
```

What if we made this change at run time like this?

```
user = User.find(42)
user.extend(UserAttributeConverter)
user.convert_attributes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single responsibility principle, based on my knowledge and research [here](http://www.oodesign.com/single-responsibility-principle.html), and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), is defined for a particular context. By this definition, the location of the text that defines the functionality doesn't necessarily matter. Extracting functionality from the class into a module (at least as the example shows) with only one purpose does not seem to extract the responsibility of `convert_attributes`, but rather shift it to a different file which is still bound to `User`. My assessment would be that a true extraction of this responsibility would perhaps be to create a class as such:

```
class UserAttributeConverter
  def self.convert_attributes(first_name, last_name, email)
    { username: self.email , name: "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}" }
  end
end
```

This gives three benefits. First is a simpler test case, we no longer need a `User` to test the functionality of `covert_attributes`. Second the `User` model is no longer responsible for what is a cosmetic change to its data. Third is that this approach removes the side effects associated with the instance implementation of `convert_attributes`.

To summarize, I do not think that extracting the functionality as you have changes your adherence to the SRP. To truly gain single responsibility, I believe a (breaking) change to the class interface would be required.

Comment: It's possible that the side-effects are desired.

Comment: Very true, but all things being equal, I would prefer explicit than implicit state change. To each their own.